# RxJava: chaining observables

Tags: java, android, scala, promise, rx-java

Is it possible to implement something like next chaining using RxJava:

```
loginObservable()
   .then( (someData) -> {
      // returns another Observable<T> with some long operation
      return fetchUserDataObservable(someData);

   }).then( (userData) -> {
      // it should be called when fetching user data completed (with userData of type T)
      cacheUserData(userData);

   }).then( (userData) -> {
      // it should be called after all previous operations completed
      displayUserData()

   }).doOnError( (error) -> {
      //do something
   })
```

I found this library very interesting, but can't figure our how to chain requests where each other depends on previous.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Sure, RxJava supports `.map` which does this. From the RxJava Wiki:

[image: map]

Basically, it'd be:

```
loginObservable()
   .switchMap( someData -> fetchUserDataObservable(someData) )
   .map( userData -> cacheUserData(userData) )
   .subscribe(new Subscriber<YourResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
           // observable stream has ended - no more logins possible
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onNext(YourType yourType) {
            displayUserData();
        }
    });
```

Comment: As i understand map transforms one value to other (for example, int -> String). So even if i return Observable<T> from first map, second map will be called immediately with userData of type Observable<T>, but i want it to be called with type T when fetchUserData completes

Comment: I think [`switchMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#switchmap) might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, seems like switchMap what i want. I would accept it if you put it as answer

Comment: @Mikhail sorry, my bad - was afk and didn't read the comment. `switchMap` is indeed what you need if you're consuming an observable.

Comment: Also, "flatMap" gives you the typical chaining behavior, comparable to Promises chained as `then`.

Comment: Can I use chain multiple calls with `switchMap`?

Comment: Can someone please answer this question: [Multiple task in an observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391853/running-two-sequential-task-in-an-observable).

Answer (score 15):

This is the top post when Googling *RxJava chain observables* so I'll just add another common case where you wouldn't want to *transform* the data you receive, but chain it with another action (setting the data to a database, for example). Use `.flatmap()`. Here's an example:

```
mDataManager
    .fetchQuotesFromApi(limit)
    .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
    .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
    // OnErrorResumeNext and Observable.error() would propagate the error to
    // the next level. So, whatever error occurs here, would get passed to
    // onError() on the UI side.
    .onErrorResumeNext(Function { Observable.error<List<Quote>>(it) })
    .flatMap { t: List<Quote> ->
        // Chain observable as such
        mDataManager.setQuotesToDb(t).subscribe(
            {},
            { e { "setQuotesToDb() error occurred: ${it.localizedMessage}" } },
            { d { "Done server set" } }
        )
        Observable.just(t)
    }
    .subscribeBy(
        onNext = {},
        onError = { mvpView?.showError("No internet connection") },
        onComplete = { d { "onComplete(): done with fetching quotes from api" } }
    )
```

This is RxKotlin2, but the idea is the same with RxJava & RxJava2:

### Quick explanation:

- we try to fetch some data (quotes in this example) from an api with `mDataManager.fetchQuotesFromApi()`
- We subscribe the observable to do stuff on `.io()` thread and show results on `.ui()` thread.
- `onErrorResumeNext()` makes sure that whatever error we encounter from fetching data is caught in this method. I wanna terminate the entire chain when there is an error there, so I return an `Observable.error()`
- `.flatmap()` is the chaining part. I wanna be able to set whatever data I get from the API to my database. I'm not transforming the data I received using `.map()`, I'm simply doing *something else* with that data **without** transforming it.
- I subscribe to the last chain of observables. If an error occurred with fetching data (first observable), it would be handled (in this case, propagated to the subscribed `onError()`) with `onErrorResumeNext()`
- I am very conscious that I'm subscribing to the DB observable (inside `flatmap()`). Any error that occurs through this observable will **NOT** be propagated to the last `subscribeBy()` methods, since it is handled inside the `subscribe()` method inside the `.flatmap()` chain.

The code comes from [this project](https://github.com/Obaied/Sohan) which is located here: https://github.com/Obaied/Sohan/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/obaied/dingerquotes/ui/start/StartPresenter.kt

Comment: Instead of using flatMap() and returning an Observable.just(t) you can use a map() and simply return t. Be aware that both versions dont wait on the result of  mDataManager.setQuotesToDb() and return before its completed.

Answer (score 0):

try using scan()

```
Flowable.fromArray(array).scan(...).subscribe(...)
```